# Domain Hosting on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis

I had written a WCF service to Host Domain on IIS ,and I had hosted that WCF service to IIS. My Code is

```
 public bool HostWebsiteToIIS(string DomainName)
        {
             bool Hosted = false;
            try
            {
                string DomainNameRecord = "";

                if (DomainName.ToLower().Contains(".com"))
                {
                    DomainNameRecord = "www." + DomainName.ToLower();

                }
                else{
                     DomainNameRecord = "www." + DomainName.ToLower()+".com";

                }
                using (ServerManager manager = ServerManager.OpenRemote("Host"))
                {
                    manager.Sites["Default Web Site"].Bindings.Add("*:80:" + DomainNameRecord, "http");
                    manager.CommitChanges();

                    Hosted = true;
                }
                return Hosted;
            }
            catch
            {
                return Hosted;
            }
        }
```

this is method I had used in my WCF, but this is throwing Exception as

> cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions

I had tried following steps

In Windows Explorer, locate the web.config file that is associated with the Web site.
Right-click the web.config file
Click Properties.
Click the Security tab, and then click Edit.
Click Add.
In the Enter the object names to select box, type computername\IIS_IUSRS, click Check Names, and then click OK. 
Note Computername is a placeholder for the computer name.
Click to select the Read check box, and then click OK.
In the Web.config Properties dialog box, click OK.

but this is not working for me 
please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Microsoft.Web.Administration` API you are using requires the code to run under an account that has administrator permissions on the target IIS machine.

In your case, the error message simply indicates that the executing account have no such permission. The file it refers to is the applicationHost.config of IIS, not your web.config. Changing that file's NTFS permission is useless.

Comment: Hey Lex, I had open VS and IIS with Admin Credential only, still there is the same exception

Comment: @Aakash then replace "Host" with a valid host name or IP address of an IIS server that you want to manage.

Comment: the "Host " is only a demo I had given example over here ,but I am having the correct IP address at my end ,Is this issue is because of WCF services?

Comment: @Aakash what's the pool identity? Do you use your own account which is the administrator on that IIS server? Run VS as administrator is useless when you host the code on IIS.

Comment: Can you please give me suggestion what I should do for "Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions".my Pool identity is ApplicationPoolIdentity ,Managed pipeline as integrated

Comment: @Aakash you cannot use ApplicationPoolIdentity which has far less permissions than required. As my first line of answer emphasises, that account to use the MWA API must be the admin on the target machine. The API was designed in that way, and the primary requirement must be fulfilled.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out I just Change the Application Pool Identity to Local System ,my Code Worked.

Comment: @Aakash one last thing you should notice is that running a web app under Local System can raise security risks. Consult a security expert to see what are the measures you need to take so as to minimize the impact.

Answer (score 0):

Click on Application Pool ->Right Click on WCF Service Hosted->Go To Advance Setting->Within process select  identity ->change "Application Pool" to "Local System" it works.

Comment: One last thing you should notice is that running a web app under Local System can raise security risks. Consult a security expert to see what are the measures you need to take so as to minimize the impact. (duplicate it so as to warn readers)